# Magento2 : Separate Login and Shipping Methods from Shipping Step

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, login, checkout-page

I wanted to Separate `login` and `Shipping methods` from Shipping Step in Magento 2 on **Checkout page** ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you a bit with that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169969/magento2-add-login-form-in-checkout-page

Comment: @Shashi have you got any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

I propose two solutions :

**First solution:**

You can create a new step in checkout like in the documentation : [https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html]

In this step, you create a new form with login/password fields and send data with a custom webapi.xml to your custom controller to process login like Magento.

**Second solution:**

You can create a new page with a controller and layout (classic process). In your controller's method, you check if the customer is logged or not. If he is, you redirect your customer to checkout.

Create a controller to receive your new login form and redirect the customer to checkout after executing the Magento login process.

Don't forget to edit checkout URLs in cart pages.

For best practices, I suggest the first solution, but if you don't want your login page in the checkout or if you don't want to use Knockout, you have the second solution ;-)

Regards.