# Magento 2: Need customer Sign-In/registraion form in checkout page

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, login, payment

When a user who is not logged in (anonymous) clicks Proceed to checkout, I want them the be taken to the login page. Then, after they've logged in or registered, they should be taken back to the checkout page.
check several link like  [Magento2: Add login form in checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169969/magento2-add-login-form-in-checkout-page).
but did not get any exact clearification.